# How to load video in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to load video in extjs 
I tried window but window creating new url (do not want to change url )

can I use Ext.XTemplate ?

Comment: maybe this solution will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404584/play-video-in-extjs

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you using? There is several options based on that.